# C++ - can't assign top-const pointer to another non-const pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

My compiler gives me error when I try to compile this. It tells me that

```
p1 = p2;
```

from this :

```
int main ()
{
    int var, *p1;
    const int *p2 = &var;
    p1 = p2;
    return 0;
}
```

is invalid conversion (const int --> int). Var is not const so it shouldn't hinder. I get that p2 can't be used to change value of var, but I think it should just assign adress if var to p1.

I know that this:

```
    p1 = &var;
```

yields the same result, but what interests me is why the former doesn't work. It is just out of curiosity about inner workings of C++.

Sorry about my languages (C++ and English), I'm not programmer, nor native speaker.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can never use `p2` to modify an `int` it points to. If you could assign it `p2` to a `int*` then you would gain the ability to modify it. Consider the case  where `p2` actually pointed to a `const int`. The assignment `p1 = p2` would allow you to assign a value to a `const` object.

Comment: The compiler does not care about `var`. There's no `var` in `p1 = p2`. In `p1 = p2` you have an attempt to convert `const int *` to `int *`. This is not allowed in C++.

Comment: I think what might be confusing you is that `var` is *actually* mutable, even though it was assigned to a pointer to const, and that you think the compiler should be able to figure this out and allow an assignment to a pointer to non-const? That opens a can of worms in flow analysis and would be impossible for a compiler to always get right. It would also be confusing to the programmer in more complicated code than above.

Comment: This is a mater of *rights* management. An analogy: just becuse some file is mutable does not mean that everyone who has access to that file should be allowed to modify it. The same thing happens in C++. If you have a `const int *` pointer it means that you have rights to read that `int`, but you don't have rights to modify it. You cannot simply "upgrade" your rights by nochalantly converting that pointer to `int *`. The compiler will not allow it.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emm... Declared type of `p1` is `int *`. And type of `p2` in `const int *`.
 So you want to assign `const int*` to `int*`, which isn't allowed. 
`p1 = &var` is allowed, because `var` has `int` type, not `const int`.

Comment: I think OP is asking *why* there is a rule forbidding the assignment from `const int*` to `int*`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Maybe. :) I think he was mislead by the fact that if it's legal `b=c` and `a=c`, then it should be legal `a=b`. But assignment operators are not such transitive, because they use kind of casting.

Comment: I was confused because I knew that `var` can be changed and didn't realise that `p2` is not able to "tell" the compiler that `var` is not const as that information is not available to compiler. So it is forbidden to assign `const int*` to `int*` because we don't know whether `const int*` is pointing to constant or not. And we can't assign `const int` to `int*`. Right?

Comment: @LukášJ. Yes, `p2` doesn't remember that `var` can be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You simply cannot assign a pointer to constant to another pointer.
For example P1 is pointer which is pointing to a constant value, If you give the address of this const int to another pointer, So that can modify the the INT which we want to be constatnt.