# C++ function with const pointer parameter

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I am learning about linked lists in my programming class right now. The following code is what compiles and works:

```
struct Node {
    int data;    
    Node *link;
   };

// this function compiles and works
size_t list_length(const Node* head_ptr) {
    size_t size{};
    for ( ; head_ptr != nullptr; head_ptr = head_ptr->link) {
        size++;    
    }
    return size;
}
```

The following implementation of the list_length function does not compile:

```
// this function gives a compile times error
size_t list_length(const Node* head_ptr) {
    size_t size{};
    Node *ptr = head_ptr;
    for ( ; ptr != nullptr; ptr = ptr->link) {
        size++;    
    }
    return size;
}
```

I am confused about the const qualifier. In this case, I know it means that the argument cannot be changed within the function. I have two questions:

1. In the version of list_length that works, why can the for-loop change the value of head_ptr if head_ptr is a const variable? As the loop iterates, is it not changing the value of head_ptr?
2. In the version of list_length that does not compile, why can I not assign the value of head_ptr to new pointer variable?

Comment: [What is the difference between const int*, const int * const, and int const *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const/1143272#1143272)

Comment: Remember `const` can refer to the pointer itself, or the thing it points *at*.

Comment: Side note: Ask your teacher to mention that after this lesson is over you should never write lists like this again and just use std::list. It seems a lot of teachers do not teach C++, but (mis)use C++ to be able to show "low level control of memory".

Comment: Maybe reading this lessons helps you too : https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/pointers-and-const/

Comment: I wonder when C++ will be taught without forcing pointers on the students first and foremost, as that's basically teaching "fancy C". Perhaps 2038. While you'll obviously need to do what's necessary to pass this course, it's worth mentioning that modern C++ can be done with very few pointers at all, and it's *considerably* more pleasant to work with that way.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Most C++ educators give a C+ course at best.

Comment: @tadman Teachers should use "C" for that, but then they don't have "classes". So they misuse C++ to teach low-level concepts but totally forget to mention this is not how C++ is used in practice.

Comment: @tadman I concur :) Or at least they teach some kind of Frankenstein mix of "C" and "C++"

Comment: @OP : Can you give this to your teacher and tell him to use it in some way in his training material? https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines. If only to tell you not to keep doing things the way you are learning them now.

Comment: @OP sorry to hi-jack your question like this. We're just a bit passionate about C++ ;)

Comment: @tadman That change will be short lived. The world will come to an end at 03:14:07 UTC on 19 January 2038.

Comment: If you're teaching a C++ class to implement things like linked lists, then you probably also want to use pointers, _but_ if you're going to do that, budget time to show them how to encapsulate the pointers to be invisible to users of the linked list.

Comment: See dupe: [C++ - can't assign top-const pointer to another non-const pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45067435/c-cant-assign-top-const-pointer-to-another-non-const-pointer)

Comment: Generally spoken, declarations mimic usage -- `const Node *p` declares something that can be changed (it is not const)  and, when dereferenced (`*p`), yields a type `const Node`. By contrast, `Node * const p` is something const (`p` itself!) which cannot be changed and, when dereferenced, yields a value of a plain `Node` which can very well be changed.

Answer (score 2):

In the second case you are trying to create a pointer to a non-`const` `Node` from a pointer to `const` one. The compiler will not allow this as it may cause problems elsewhere. You can either use a pointer to a `const Node` for the copy, or use `const_cast` to bypass the error check. So either:

```
const Node *ptr = head_ptr; // make ptr to const to match the source item
```

or

```
Node *ptr = const_cast<Node*>(head_ptr); // cast away the const
```

In case 2 here, the compiler allows the cast as you are telling it that you know what you are doing.

Comment: Re "In the second case you are trying to create a non-const pointer from a const one": No. the OP is trying to create a pointer **to non-const** from a pointer **to const**. None of the pointers themselves is const.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Thank you, I have edited ny answer.

Answer (score 1):

*1. In the version of list_length that works, why can the for-loop change the value of head_ptr if head_ptr is a const variable? As the loop iterates, is it not changing the value of head_ptr?*

`head_ptr` is a pointer to a variable of datatype "const Node". Therefore `head_ptr` is not a constant, yes, it is just a normal pointer. So you can just change it freely as you wish.

*2. In the version of list_length that does not compile, why can I not assign the value of head_ptr to new pointer variable?*

Because `head_ptr` is a pointer to a variable of datatype "const Node", and `ptr` is presumably a pointer to a variable of datatype "Node", so this is a mismatch.

Reference: [const (C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/const-cpp?view=msvc-170)

Answer (score 1):

> I am confused about the const qualifier. In this case, I know it means that the argument cannot be changed within the function.

What you are describing as what you know is actually slightly off.  In this code, the argument is a *non-const* pointer to a const Node object.  The argument can change, but the thing it points to cannot.

`const` affects the thing to its left...  UNLESS there's nothing to its left, and then it affect the thing to its right.  (This means you can read the type right-to-left correctly:  `Node const * head_ptr` means "head_ptr is a (non-const) pointer to a const Node"

What you are describing is a different thing, a const pointer to a non-const node, and that would look like this: `Node * const head_ptr`  ("head_ptr is a const pointer to a (non-const) Node")

> I have two questions:  In the version of list_length that works, why can the for-loop change the value of head_ptr if head_ptr is a const variable? As the loop iterates, is it not changing the value of head_ptr?

`head_ptr` is *not* const.  The thing it points to is const.  Modifying head_ptr is perfectly fine.

> In the version of list_length that does not compile, why can I not assign the value of head_ptr to new pointer variable?

It's attempting to convert a pointer-to-const-Node to a pointer-to-Node.  Such a conversion is unsafe, because if you start with something that could not be modified, but it was allowed to make such a conversion, then you could too easily bypass the const-ness by simply looking at the pointer differently.  C++ requires you to be more forceful to remove const, since doing it incorrectly can result in undefined behavior if you end up modifying an object that actually was declared const (as opposed to gaining const qualification later.)